# date wise JOIN in Hive making issue

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to join two tables based on following condition.
my table A looks like

```
  id,date
  12,20190114
  13,20190118
  14,20190123
```

Table B looks like

```
  id,date
  13,20190108
  12,20190108
  13,20190101
  13,20190115
  14,20190129
  14,20190122
```

when i apply join Condition , i need to consider followings

```
   1. id should be same for both tables
   2. date from table A should join with the date previous to the table B
    dates(table B dates are weekly basis... I need to find the current week).
```

That is table B dates are weekly dates. for example for id=13 table A date is 20190118 and the corresponding date from the table B is 20180115 , that is the current week the table A part of...

my result should after JOIN be like

```
  id,a.date,b.date
  13,20190118,2018015
  12,20190114,20190108
  14,20190123,20190122
```

can some one tell me how to acheieve this in hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work in Hive?

```
select a.id, a.date, max(b.date)
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id and b.date <= a.date
group by a.id, a.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d04e0c6793b3aa362d7cd44a9b360312) is a db<>fiddle showing that it works on the data provides, albeit in Postgres.

Comment: "on a.id = b.id and b.date <= a.date" doent suite for my case .. as i need to find previous week date corresponding to date from A table.  incase of id 13, my a.date is 20190118 and b.date is 20190115..not 20190101 or 20190108....

Comment: @BigD . . . The code does what your question specifies.  The question is whether or not it runs in Hive.